# ListView Items Occupy Remaining Space in Vertical Orientation

Tags: android

Good day all, have a small issue here. I have an EditText and a ListView inside a RelativeLayout. The ListView is populated by items in a string-array using an ArrayAdapter. The size of thr array is 5 and the ListView Items is a Table Layout with table row Layout Parameters set to both Fill_Parent same as the ListView Widget. Now I want the Listview Items to fill up and occupy the remaining screen space. but since they are only few Items, it behaves like it's using wrap_content. Any Idea how to stretch out this ListView Items? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you can use a linear layout instead of a relative layout it would solve all your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/yourListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

Comment: fill_parent and match_parent provide the same behavior, mainly that the view will "fill" or "match" the space occupied by its parent view.  Having said that, fill_parent is deprecated, so it would be better to set both the width and height attributes to "match_parent"